# Why I can't get the client IP address which is connecting through VPN

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a website created using ASP.NET which is hosted internally. To access the website, user needs to use the provided VPN. I need to capture the client's public IP address, but I'm always getting a private IP address which is VPN IP gateway.

The flow is:

1. User log in using FortiClient VPN.
2. Open the browser to access the website.

> **In the process no 2, when the user tries to log in, I'm trying to get the user client's IP address. But always get FortiGate IP address**

**Is there any way to get the actual client IP address instead of a VPN IP gateway?**

Below are is my code to get the IP address

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"]))

  return Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"].Split(',')[0].Trim();

else
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"]))
    
    return Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"].Split(',')[0].Trim();
  
  else
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    
      return Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].Split(',')[0].Trim();

    else
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]))

        return Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].Split(',')[0].Trim();

      else

        return Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using a VPN, not a proxy. That is to say: those HTTP headers will (sometimes) be added by HTTP proxies. VPNs don't concern themselves with such high-level data.

Comment: @John, so in summary, I can't get actual client IP address?

Comment: Unless you have access to query that information from the VPN server itself, probably not.